# Installing websocket without command prompt?

Tags: node.js, websocket, hosting

Is there a way to install web socket without command prompt? I tried to install nodejs (intend to use socket.io) in my hosting but don't have the command prompt..

Comment: Do you mean without a shell?

Comment: Ya without command line interfaces like shell / bash, etc.

Comment: This question is very general. Help us answer your question by editing your question and providing more details such as your host and any solutions you tried.

Comment: Apparently I asked my hosting support regarding installing nodejs through command prompt but they said my hosting isn't a VPS, as installing websockets like socket.io, I believe it requires a command line interface to do that. Was looking out for alternatives that doesn't require command line interface.